# Passing data from children to parent with n children in Angular without emiting in each component along the way

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-event-emitter

If I have this components hierarchy in Angular:
[image]

And there is something happening in component F that B should know about.
One way I can do it is using `emit()` in F and pass it along the way up to A, but this will require me to emit event in **each** component E,D and C, even though they don't care and should not care about the data being emitted - So in F I will write

```
export class F .... {
  ...

  @Output() emitterName: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  doSomething(data) {
   ...
   this.emitterName.emit(data);
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, class E should call F like `<app-f-selector (emitterName)="setData($event)"><app-f-selector/>`

And in E, I should create a new function `setData()` that just emits the event up to D:

```
export class E .... {
  ...

  @Output() emitterName: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  setData(data) {
   ...
   this.emitterName.emit(data);
  }
  ...
}
```

Now again I should do **the same** for D and C.
That looks really bad, is there some elegant way in Angular to pass data from children component up to parent component, when there are n children along the way without code duplication?
Something like [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)?

Comment: use a shared service and `subscribe` to data changes, exactly what they were intended for.

Comment: A singleton service would be a good fit for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (not checked, but as a guide):

```
export class MySharedService {

  private data$ = new Subject<any>();
  public setData(data: any) {
      this.data$.next(data);
  }
  public getData(): Observable<any> {
      return this.data$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

then in any component that requires this data, inject via constructor and subscribe to changes:

```
this.mySharedService.getData().subscribe(data => ...do something here);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using share service ie.

```
// shared.service.ts
export class SharedService  {
  private updateComp = new Subject<any>();
  public updateComp$ = this.updateComp.asObservable();
    
    public updateComponent(data: any) {
    this.updateComp.next(data);
  }
}

// C OR D Component .ts enject sharedService in constructor
ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.updateComp$.subscribe((res: any) => {
    //you code...
    });
}

// F Component .ts call share service method i.e.
this.sharedService.updateComponent({ you data});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you may have only one parent with type "A", you can inject in the children and call it directly.

```
export class F {
  constructor(
    private parentA: AComponent
  ){}

  setData(data) {
   this.parentA.doSomething(data);
  }
}
```

But I would not recommend such a structure, since this makes component F tightly coupled to component A. In our project, we use this approach only to implement custom UI components, which are dynamically generated.